# making a customized short url

Tags: android

I want to shortened my url but want it in a customized way.

I used this

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        String urlTemplate = "http://tinyurl.com/api-create.php?url=%s";
        String uri = String.format(urlTemplate, URLEncoder.encode(l));
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(uri);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream in = entity.getContent();

        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        // TODO: Support other encodings
        String enc = "utf-8";
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(in, enc);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
        String tinyUrl = bufferedReader.readLine();
```

but this is giving me a link starting with tinyurl, but i want a customize url like "zaiff.co/mynum/mycode". Is there any api to do this from google ar third party?

Comment: So all in all, this question is not about Android or your code at all? It is just about 3rd party URL shorteners?

Comment: yes, this is about url shortners and i am not getting any api to use in android, Can you please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this is an appropriate answer, but here are some URL shorteners officially offering aliasing through their API's (unlike TinyURL):

- [BudURL](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/budurl/frames) (a paid shortening service) offers aliasing through their API.
- [is.gd](http://www.memset.com/tools/) allows for a `shorturl` parameter to explicitly specify your desired name.